# day calculation error when using calendar extender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having problem in day calculation error by using calendar extender in asp.ney with c# framework 3.5. I am using this method to calculate days:

```
TimeSpan days = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1_CalendarExtender).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2_CalendarExtender));
```

Through this method I am getting the days calculation wrong and if the days are of two different months then it throws an exception. I need the solution for bothe framework 3.5 and 4.0.

Comment: What are `TextBox1_CalendarExtender` and `TextBox2_CalendarExtender`? You have to parse the `Text` property of the `TextBoxes` not the extenders.

Comment: And please give sample values and the unexpected results, as well as the exception. Basically you've given us very little information here.

Answer (score 0):

You generally have to use a control's .Text property to get the displayed value in the control.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1_CalendarExtender) //is going to convert the control
Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1_CalendarExtender.Text) //is going to convert the value
```

There are other properties on the calendar extender control that may already return the SelectedDate, but I am not familiar with that specific control.